# How to convert SQL query to MongoDB

Tags: sql, mongodb

```
SELECT s_name FROM supplier 
WHERE s_suppkey = ALL
(SELECT s_suppkey FROM supplier
WHERE s_nationkey > 50 AND s_acctbal= 9658.99 )
```

I don't know how to do this part

```
WHERE s_suppkey = ALL
    (SELECT s_suppkey FROM supplier
    WHERE s_nationkey > 50 AND s_acctbal= 9658.99 )
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `=ANY`?

Comment: No because it would return nothing by using ANY. Whith ALL it returns all the suppliers key.

Comment: And why not simply `SELECT s_name FROM supplier WHERE s_nationkey > 50 AND s_acctbal= 9658.99`?

Comment: Because it returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.supplier.find( {}, { $and : [  {  s_nationkey : { '$gt' : 50 } }, { s_acctbal : 9658.99 } ] } ,{s_suppkey:1} )
```

But does not return suppliers name!

Answer (score 0):

You SQL looks a bit strange. For Mongo try this one:

```
db.supplier.find({ s_nationkey: { '$gt': 50 }, s_acctbal: 9658.99 }, {s_name :1} )
```